# Kali Linux issue while downloading scrcpy

Tags: apt, sudo, kali-linux

I am a kali linux beginner, So after installing I was following a tutorial I needed to do sudo apt-get install scrcpy on the root user.
I am getting error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package scrcpy
```

I also tried this link to solve my problem but no help. `https://ftlinuxcourse.com/e-unable-to-locate-package-kali-linux-2020-problem-solved`

What I am using: kali linux 4Virtual Box, i386 2020 Virtual box 6.1 KALI LINUX

Regards, Saad

Comment: I am also a beginner

Comment: do not use Kali to learn Linux .... install a user friendly distribution, such as Mint or Ubuntu

Comment: I know some of the important commands

Comment: the problem is that you do not know if you made a mistake, or if Kali is broken ... it would make sense to eliminate one trap from your learning

Comment: Sorry I understand I should start with Ubuntu or something simpler but I want to learn this for white hats and I have been told ubuntu is an OS by someone but I think it's like a part of linux

Comment: Ubuntu is dist for linux

Comment: Ubuntu or Mint are not simpler ... they just work out of the box without having to configure a bunch of stuff

Comment: Yeah and Thank you very much for helping and replying
So do I need some specific internet setttings to run nmap and other things like sslstrip

Answer (score 1):

The package is only available for debian Sid and Ubuntu 20.04 through `apt`.

You can install `scrcpy` on kali linux through [`snap`](https://snapcraft.io/scrcpy):

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install snapd
sudo snap install core
sudo systemctl unmask snapd
sudo systemctl enable --now snapd
sudo snap install scrcpy
```

add the following line to your `~/.zshrc`:

```
echo "alias scrcpy='/snap/bin/scrcpy'" >> ~/.zshrc
```

then:

```
source ~/.zshrc
scrcpy
```

Comment: I get this error and I also know we can download from snap but I then get the error

`error: cannot communicate with server: Post "http://localhost/v2/snaps/scrcpy": dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect: no such file or directory
`

Comment: so @GAD3R how can I run this like I tried just `scrcpy` it says no command like that but it works fine when I do `snap run scrcpy`. Just asking can I do with just scrcpy and what does that unmask mean I know systemctl is for systemd

Comment: How do I cd into .zshrc and no worries I needed to just check